# Function Array<Optional<T>> -> Optional<Array<T>>

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift2, option-type

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
extension Array<Optional<T>> {   
  func unwrap() -> Optional<Array<T>> {
    let a = self.flatMap() { a in
      switch a {
      case Optional.Some(let x): return [x]
      case Optional.None: return []
      }
    }
    if a.count == self.count {
      return Optional.Some(a)
    } else {
      return Optional.None
    }   
  } 
}
```

But, it doesn't compiles with error `Use of undeclared type T`.
Here is how I want to use it:

```
let a = [Optional.Some(2), Optional.Some(3), Optional.Some(4)]
let b = [Optional.Some(1), Optional.None]
a.unwrap() // Optional[2, 3, 4]
b.unwrap() // nil
```

How can I get around with this? Or there is no such possibility in swift?

Comment: The syntax `extension Array<Optional<T>>` is illegal and meaningless. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @matt added to question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
protocol OptionalType {
    typealias W
    var optional: W? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    typealias W = Wrapped
    var optional: W? { return self }
}

extension Array where Element: OptionalType {
    func unwrap() -> [Element.W]? {
        return reduce(Optional<[Element.W]>([])) { acc, e in
            acc.flatMap { a in e.optional.map { a + [$0] } }
        }
    } 
}
```

And then,

```
let a: [Int?] = [1,   2, 3]
let b: [Int?] = [1, nil, 3]

a.unwrap() // ==> [1, 2, 3]
b.unwrap() // ==> nil
```

Comment: That's pretty clever! Nice.

Comment: Looks awesome, but also very confusing. Can you suggest, where can I read more about type system in swift?

Comment: @AlfredZien Sorry, only one resource I've read about Swift is Apple's. I guess my experience of "Scala" and "Haskell" helps me very often.

Comment: is there a less ugly solution?

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 4

Inspired by the solution by @findall, this works with Swift 4:

```
protocol OptionalType {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optional: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var optional: Wrapped? { return self }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: OptionalType {
    func removeNils() -> [Iterator.Element.Wrapped] {
        return self.flatMap { $0.optional }
    }
}
```

### Test:

```
class UtilitiesTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func testRemoveNils() {
        let optionalString: String? = nil
        let strings: [String?] = ["Foo", optionalString, "Bar", optionalString, "Baz"]
        XCTAssert(strings.count == 5)
        XCTAssert(strings.removeNils().count == 3)
        let integers: [Int?] = [2, nil, 4, nil, nil, 5]
        XCTAssert(integers.count == 6)
        XCTAssert(integers.removeNils().count == 3)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

findall's solution works, although I think it's more readable to just avoid generics for this case:

```
func unwrap<Element>(optionalArray : [Element?]) -> [Element]? {
    let unwrappedArray = optionalArray.flatMap { (a) -> [Element] in
        switch a {
        case Optional.Some(let x): return [x]
        case Optional.None: return []
        }
    }

    return unwrappedArray.count == optionalArray.count ? Optional.Some(unwrappedArray) : Optional.None
}
```

Usage:

```
let a = [Optional.Some(2), Optional.Some(3), Optional.Some(4)]
let b = [Optional.Some(1), Optional.None]

// Both are [Int]?
let unwrappedA = unwrap(a) // [2, 3, 4]
let unwrappedB = unwrap(b) // nil
```

See also: [How to determine if a generic is an optional in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25064644/1445366)